# Prove the derivative of the series is not continuous

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, continuity

Consider
$$
S(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^2(1+x^{2n})}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\left\vert \frac{x^n}{n^2(1+x^{2n})} \right\vert &= \left\vert \frac{1}{n^2(\frac{1}{x^n}+x^n)} \right\vert \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2n^2}, \text{ using } \left\vert z + \frac{1}{z} \right\vert \geq 2
\end{align}
$$

$S$ is therefore normally convergent everywhere and thus continuous.
Plotting $S$ (in red) and its derivative (in blue) gives the following graph

[image]

How would one show that the detivative of $S$ is not continuous at $x=1$? Can we compute the value of $S'$ at $1^-$ and $1^+$?

Comment: I would start by finding the derivative of the inner term of the sum. This should be pretty easy to do. Then you could see if that power series converges or not (You might be able to manipulate the term to be of the form $a_n x^n$).

Comment: I don't think these edits improve the question enough. For example, we are still left wondering why we/you care about this function. Why are you asking the question?

Comment: I'm asking the question because the graph is totally unexpected, especially for a normally convergent series, that's a sufficient reason for me. I'm curious about what argument can be used to prove the statement I couldn't prove, and it seems way harder thet it looks.

Answer (score -1):

To show that the derivative of S is not continuous at x=1, we can compute the left and right derivatives of S at x=1 and show that they are not equal.

We have $S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n^2(1+x^{2n})}$, which converges uniformly on every compact interval $[a,b]$ with $a>0$. Hence, we can differentiate $S$ term-by-term to obtain:

$S'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2(1+x^{2n})} \cdot nx^{n-1}$

Now, consider the left and right derivatives of $S$ at $x=1$. We have:

$S'{-}(1) = \lim{x\to 1^-} S'(x) = \lim_{x\to 1^-} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2(1+x^{2n})} \cdot nx^{n-1}$

and

$S'{+}(1) = \lim{x\to 1^+} S'(x) = \lim_{x\to 1^+} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2(1+x^{2n})} \cdot nx^{n-1}$

To evaluate these limits, we can use the fact that the series converges uniformly on every compact interval $[a,b]$ with $a>0$, and hence we can interchange the limit and summation operations. Then, we get:

$S'{-}(1) = \sum{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 \cdot 2} = \frac{\pi^2}{12}$

and

$S'{+}(1) = \sum{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 \cdot 2} \cdot (-1)^{n-1} = -\frac{\pi^2}{12}$

Since $S'{-}(1) \neq S'{+}(1)$, the derivative of $S$ is not continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: You forgot to differentiate the denominator...

Comment: And you are right to want to calculate $\lim_{1^\pm}S',$ but wrong to call them "the left and right derivatives of S at x=1" (the latter are equal to the former, but 1) this would need an argument 2) they are anyway off topic).